# How to give shadder effect with anyFile.vsh and anyFile.fsh in android camera?

Tags: android, android-layout, opengl-es, android-emulator, android-widget

In My application i have to use the Android Camera, and OpenGLES.
I have also have to give the effect to the Camera Vision with two files called one.vsh and one.fsh But i dont know how to implement that file in OpenGLES.

Even i also dont know how to implement android camera to work with OPENGLES to do effect with that two files.

Please help me for this.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I don't have a test about Android camera to use such effect on it.
But ofcourse, you can use the shader file in the `onSurfaceCreated` method as like below:

```
//
// Initialize the shader and program object
//
public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 glUnused, EGLConfig config) {
    String vShaderStr = "uniform mat4 u_mvpMatrix;         \n"
            + "attribute vec4 a_position;                  \n"
            + "void main()                                 \n"
            + "{                                           \n"
            + "   gl_Position = u_mvpMatrix * a_position;  \n"
            + "}                                           \n";


    String fShaderStr = "precision mediump float;                  \n"
            + "void main()                                         \n"
            + "{                                                   \n"
            + "  gl_FragColor = vec4( 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 );        \n"
            + "}                                                   \n";

    // Load the shaders and get a linked program object
    mProgramObject = ESShader.loadProgram(vShaderStr, fShaderStr);

    // Get the attribute locations
    mPositionLoc = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(mProgramObject, "position");

    // Get the uniform locations
    mMVPLoc = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgramObject, "u_mvpMatrix");

    // Generate the vertex data
    mCube.genCube(1.0f);

    // Starting rotation angle for the cube
    mAngle = 45.0f;

    GLES20.glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
}
```

Just replace the `String` that you want to use for vertex shader and fragment shader.
Hope this helps.